# How to restore roulette wheel when popping one element out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created roulette wheel function for random number generation purpose. I don't want repeat number to be appear, so I'm popping generated number out of queue. But i want FULL CIRCLE WITH NEW VALUES(EXCLUDING LAST GENERATED NUMBER), when you run it for second time. right now it is not showing full circle. how do i do it? any help would be appreciated.

```js
 var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20",
            "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50"
        ];

        var startAngle = 0;
        var arc = Math.PI / (options.length / 2);
        var spinTimeout = null;

        var spinArcStart = 10;
        var spinTime = 0;
        var spinTimeTotal = 0;

        var ctx;

        document.getElementById("spin").addEventListener("click", spin);

        function byte2Hex(n) {
            var nybHexString = "0123456789ABCDEF";
            return String(nybHexString.substr((n >> 4) & 0x0F, 1)) + nybHexString.substr(n & 0x0F, 1);
        }

        function RGB2Color(r, g, b) {
            return '#' + byte2Hex(r) + byte2Hex(g) + byte2Hex(b);
        }

        function getColor(item, maxitem) {
            var phase = 0;
            var center = 128;
            var width = 127;
            var frequency = Math.PI * 2 / maxitem;

            red = Math.sin(frequency * item + 2 + phase) * width + center;
            green = Math.sin(frequency * item + 0 + phase) * width + center;
            blue = Math.sin(frequency * item + 4 + phase) * width + center;

            return RGB2Color(red, green, blue);
        }

        function drawRouletteWheel() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            if (canvas.getContext) {
                var outsideRadius = 200;
                var textRadius = 160;
                var insideRadius = 125;

                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

                ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;

                ctx.font = 'bold 14px Helvetica';

                for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
                    //ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
                    ctx.fillStyle = getColor(i, options.length);

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
                    ctx.arc(250, 250, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.fill();

                    ctx.save();
                    ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
                    ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
                    ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
                    ctx.shadowColor = "rgb(220,220,220)";
                    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                    ctx.translate(250 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius,
                        250 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
                    ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
                    var text = options[i];
                    ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
                    ctx.restore();
                }

                //Arrow
                ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
                ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
                ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
                ctx.lineTo(250 + 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
                ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (outsideRadius - 13));
                ctx.lineTo(250 - 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
                ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
                ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
                ctx.fill();
            }
        }

        function spin() {
            spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
            spinTime = 0;
            spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1000;
            rotateWheel();
        }

        function rotateWheel() {
            spinTime += 50;
            if (spinTime >= spinTimeTotal) {
                stopRotateWheel();
                return;
            }
            var spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal);
            startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
            drawRouletteWheel();
            spinTimeout = setTimeout('rotateWheel()', 30);
        }

        function stopRotateWheel() {
            clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
            var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
            var arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
            var index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
            ctx.save();
            ctx.font = 'bold 50px Helvetica, Arial';   //GENERATED NUMBER
            var text = options[index];
            ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
            ctx.restore();
            var newOptions = options.splice(index, 1);
//            options = options - options.slice(index,1);
//            options = options - index;
            
        }

        function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
            var ts = (t /= d) * t;
            var tc = ts * t;
            return b + c * (tc + -3 * ts + 3 * t);
        }

        drawRouletteWheel();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

    <input type="button" value="SPIN THE WHEEL!" style="width: 200px;height: 100px;font-weight: bold;font-size: 18px;" id='spin' />
```

Comment: A no graphical workaround would be to simply have it automatically spin again if an existing number is landed on twice. The odds will change the same as if you removed the number from the wheel.

Comment: `var arc = Math.PI / (options.length / 2);` you need to redefine `arc` value again after you splice the options array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so; redefining `arc` after your array splice

```js
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20",
            "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50"
        ];

        var startAngle = 0;
        var arc = Math.PI / (options.length / 2);
        var spinTimeout = null;

        var spinArcStart = 10;
        var spinTime = 0;
        var spinTimeTotal = 0;

        var ctx;

        document.getElementById("spin").addEventListener("click", spin);

        function byte2Hex(n) {
            var nybHexString = "0123456789ABCDEF";
            return String(nybHexString.substr((n >> 4) & 0x0F, 1)) + nybHexString.substr(n & 0x0F, 1);
        }

        function RGB2Color(r, g, b) {
            return '#' + byte2Hex(r) + byte2Hex(g) + byte2Hex(b);
        }

        function getColor(item, maxitem) {
            var phase = 0;
            var center = 128;
            var width = 127;
            var frequency = Math.PI * 2 / maxitem;

            red = Math.sin(frequency * item + 2 + phase) * width + center;
            green = Math.sin(frequency * item + 0 + phase) * width + center;
            blue = Math.sin(frequency * item + 4 + phase) * width + center;

            return RGB2Color(red, green, blue);
        }

        function drawRouletteWheel() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            if (canvas.getContext) {
                var outsideRadius = 200;
                var textRadius = 160;
                var insideRadius = 125;

                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

                ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;

                ctx.font = 'bold 14px Helvetica';

                for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
                    //ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
                    ctx.fillStyle = getColor(i, options.length);

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(250, 250, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
                    ctx.arc(250, 250, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.fill();

                    ctx.save();
                    ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
                    ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
                    ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
                    ctx.shadowColor = "rgb(220,220,220)";
                    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                    ctx.translate(250 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius,
                        250 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
                    ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
                    var text = options[i];
                    ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
                    ctx.restore();
                }

                //Arrow
                ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
                ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
                ctx.lineTo(250 + 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
                ctx.lineTo(250 + 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
                ctx.lineTo(250 + 0, 250 - (outsideRadius - 13));
                ctx.lineTo(250 - 9, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
                ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius - 5));
                ctx.lineTo(250 - 4, 250 - (outsideRadius + 5));
                ctx.fill();
            }
        }

        function spin() {
            spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
            spinTime = 0;
            spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1000;
            rotateWheel();
        }

        function rotateWheel() {
            spinTime += 50;
            if (spinTime >= spinTimeTotal) {
                stopRotateWheel();
                return;
            }
            var spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal);
            startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
            drawRouletteWheel();
            spinTimeout = setTimeout('rotateWheel()', 30);
        }

        function stopRotateWheel() {
            clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
            var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
            var arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
            var index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
            ctx.save();
            ctx.font = 'bold 50px Helvetica, Arial';   //GENERATED NUMBER
            var text = options[index];
            ctx.fillText(text, 250 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 250 + 10);
            ctx.restore();
            var newOptions = options.splice(index, 1);
//            options = options - options.slice(index,1);
//            options = options - index;
            arc = Math.PI / (options.length / 2);
            
        }

        function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
            var ts = (t /= d) * t;
            var tc = ts * t;
            return b + c * (tc + -3 * ts + 3 * t);
        }

        drawRouletteWheel();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

    <input type="button" value="SPIN THE WHEEL!" style="width: 200px;height: 100px;font-weight: bold;font-size: 18px;" id='spin' />
```

Comment: Wow! that worked well! thank you very much for help!

Comment: Kudos, Nice wheel :)